# warning: implicit declaration of function 'bin'; warning: conflicting types for 'bin'

Tags: c, binary-search

I got this error for binary search program in c, although it asked me give inputs and printed the correct output.Below is the error I got in the output window.

```
  binarysearch.c: In function 'sort': binarysearch.c:22:5: warning:
  implicit declaration of function 'bin'
  [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
       bin(a,size);//invokes bin(int,int) to find element
       ^~~ binarysearch.c: At top level: binarysearch.c:24:6: warning: conflicting types for 'bin'  void bin(int a[],int size)//finds element
  using binary sort technique and return its index
       ^~~ binarysearch.c:22:5: note: previous implicit declaration of 'bin' was here
       bin(a,size);//invokes bin(int,int) to find element
       ^~~
  Enter size of array:
```

> 1. How do I resolve the error?
> 2. What does the error mean?
> 3. Why did it still ask for inputs when an error occurred?

I made 2 functions. First function that is `void sort(int a[],int size)` sorted the array using selection sort and printed it and invoked the second function, the function below that or the second function that is `void bin(int a[],int size)` used binary search to find an element and printed its position(index+1). Then I wrote the main function.

The program is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void sort(int a[],int size)//sorts array in ascending order
{
    int min;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
        {
           if(a[j]>a[j+1])//checks if elements at position 'i' is greater than element at position (i+1) and exchanges values if true
           {
              min=a[j];
              a[j]=a[j+1];
              a[j+1]=min;
           }
        }
    }
    printf("Sorted array:");
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)//prints sorted array
    {
        printf("%d  ",a[i]);
    }
    bin(a,size);//invokes bin(int,int) to find element
}
void bin(int a[],int size)//finds element using binary sort technique and return its index
{
    int key;//stores element to be found
    printf("\nEnter element to be found:");
    scanf("%d",&key);
    int sp=0;//stores starting point which is initially 0
    int ep=size-1;//stores ending point which is initially one less than size of array
    int mid;//stores average of sp and ep
    int count=0;//counter
    printf("Occurrence is:");
    while(sp<=ep)
    {
        mid=(sp+ep)/2;
        if(a[mid]>key)//to run loop for elements that are before mid
        {
            ep=mid-1;
        }
        else if(a[mid]<key)//to run loop for elements that are after mid 
        {
            sp=mid+1;
        }
        else if(a[mid]==key)//when element is found
        {
            printf("%d",mid+1);
            count+=1;
            break;//to stop the loop
        }
    }
    if(count==0)//in case element is not found
    printf("ELEMENT NOT FOUND");
}
    int main()
    {
        int n;//stores size of array
        printf("Enter size of array:");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        int arr[n];//creates array of size n
        printf("Enter elements:");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
        }
        sort(arr,n);//invoke sort(int,int) function which later invokes bin(int,int) function
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and copy the errors into it as text rather than linking screenshots. You're also supposed to post a [mre], which in most cases won't be your entire program. That being said, an implicit declaration means the compiler is encountering a function for the first time without knowing its prototype/signature/declaration. These generally go in `.h` files, but is also common to put function declarations at the top of C files for small programs. Also looks like you're naming two functions `bin` with different arguments? There's no function overloading in C.

Comment: @yano thanks for the advice, I edited the question. I used bin only at two places. One when I made the function bin(int,int) and two when I invoked it in the first function; bin(a,size) like this. Also could you please elaborate the implicit part and also tell me how to resolve the error. Thankyou

Comment: Can't say for sure because you haven't posted code of binarysearch.c, but I'd guess you're mistakenly calling `bin` with `int, int` arguments instead of `int[], int`. The implicit declaration is the compiler saying "I don't know of a `bin` function that takes `int, int`.

Comment: Any warnings containing _"implicit declaration"_ (or something similar) is actually an error nowadays. It means that the hasn't been declared properly hasn't been declared at all.

Comment: You need to show us `binarysearch.c`. The problem is most likely _there_. Read this: [mcve]

Comment: @Jabberwocky I edited the question and added the entire program

Comment: You forgot to add a forward declaration for `bin`.  Put the following in your source file, *before* sort:  `void bin(int a[],int size);`  This is a forward declaration, and must be present if you reference a function before its definition.

Comment: @TomKarzes thanks it worked. I also wanted to ask, why did the compiler run the program even though I didn't do a forward declaration?

Comment: @SahilSingh In the absence of a forward declaration, the compiler falls back on the old default rules, which assume that the return type is `int` and that the arguments are unspecified.  It should generate a warning when this happens, but it is not a fatal error (at least not at present).  You should always fix this when you see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a routine before using it.

Either move the definition of `bin` before the definition of `sort` or put this non-definition declaration before `sort`:

```
void bin(int a[], int size);
```

Comment: thanks it worked. I also wanted to ask, why did the compiler run the program even though I didn't do a forward declaration?

Comment: @SahilSingh: In old implementations of C, functions could be used without declaring them. When the compiler saw a function call for an undeclared name, it would declare it as a function returning `int`. This is obsolete, but compilers may still accept the call and create the implicit declaration, with a warning. Generally, it is preferable to tell your compiler to use a modern language standard (as with the GCC switch `-std=c17`), turn on many warning messages (GCC `-Wall` or Clang `-Wmost` and/or other switches), and elevate warnings to errors (`-Werror`).